# Jquery UI Grid scripts

Tags: jquery-ui

Has anyone tried this grid yet? I would like to use it but I'm not sure where to start. I read [this article](http://tpeczek.blogspot.com/2011/02/early-look-at-jquery-ui-grid-in-aspnet.html) but I have some questions. Maybe some of the experts here can help.

First big question is "how can I get a copy of the code". The article points to a source but it's on some MVC trunk and I don't know how I can download the example.

Next big question. The article points so scripts:

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/grid-datamodel.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
...
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.tmpl.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/ui/jquery.ui.core.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/datamodel/dataitem.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/datamodel/datasource.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/datamodel/extractor-datasource.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/datamodel/datastore.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/datamodel/grid.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Where can I get these from?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that all of the scripts being referenced can be found in the [github branch link](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/tree/grid) he includes.

You can download a zip file by clicking the Download Now link on the right side of the page.

Answer (score 0):

you can also browse the source code (the live branch (within 10 min), and tags), and easily download multiple files:
http://view.jqueryui.com

specifically, you can view the grid, and demos:
http://view.jqueryui.com/grid/
http://view.jqueryui.com/grid/grid-spf/